# Suggest for each word I typed alternative words that are pronounced similarly

Tags: windows, text-processing, speech-recognition

I am looking for a program running on Microsoft Windows that can suggest for each word I typed alternative words that are pronounced similarly. I'm mostly interested in texts written in English.

Example with Dragon NaturallySpeaking:

[image]

My use case: I use speech recognition to write most of my texts, and I would like to have an efficient way to correct words that haven't been transcribed accurately. Some speech recognition programs provide a way to correct words but I'm looking for alternatives.

Ideally:

- the proposed words should make sense in terms of language models.
- the user may define alternatives for specific words (e.g., when a word is often transcribed inaccurately)

Any price or license is fine.

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- http://qr.ae/TbZqeO
- https://redd.it/6alvx7
- http://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=7&threadid=24311
- Some question but for Mac OS X: [Suggest for each word I typed alternative words that are pronounced similarly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/283475/20338)
- Some question but for Ubuntu: [Suggest for each word I typed alternative words that are pronounced similarly](https://askubuntu.com/q/914638/44876)

Comment: Words that are spelt differently but sound the same are called homophones _which is a specific case of a homonym_ - this might help in this search. Note that such words are region specific as well as language and dialect specific.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Thanks, good point,  I am going to keep this in mind when searching for it.

Comment: I read in your KnowBrainer question, "suggestions given by Dragon NaturallySpeaking are quite limited."  Can you provide some examples?  Also, have you asked on KnowBrainer whether it's possible to add additional choices to Dragon?

Comment: @aparente001 [Always propose a word when correcting a word in Dragon NaturallySpeaking](https://superuser.com/q/1082618/116475)

Comment: It's been a while since I used KnowBrainer, but I thought it could be used for your idea.  There is a forum and you can also call for support.  I've found the owner to be quite responsive.

Comment: @aparente001 I don't think KnowBrainer has such a feature. Definitely their forum contains much useful information.